# SQL GROUP BY with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

i have these data in an MSSQL 2012r2 table:

```
id   data1  amount
------------------
10   abc     95.00
10   NULL   312.00
20   def     16.00
30   gqi     32.00
```

Expected query result:

```
id   data1  amount
------------------
10   abc    407.00
20   def     16.00
30   gqi     32.00
```

is this possible using only sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case when` can also help you

```
select id, case when data1 is null then 'abc' else data1 end
          as data1, sum(amount) from table_name
         group by id,case when data1 is null then 'abc' else data1 end
```

Answer (score 2):

use `max()`,`sum()` aggregated function and `group by`

```
select id, max(data1),sum(amount)
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `NULL` to look like `'abc'`, then use `coalesce()`:

```
select id, coalesce(data1, 'abc') as data1,
       sum(amount) as amount
from t
group by id, coalesce(data1, 'abc');
```

This will create an arbitrary `'abc'` row if it doesn't exist.  If you just want it merged with *any* existing value:

```
select t.id, coalesce(t.data1, t2.data1) as data1,
       sum(t.amount) as amount
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.data1
      from t t2
      where t2.id = t.id and t2.data1 is  not null
     ) t2
group by t.id, coalesce(t.data1, t2.data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t1.data1,t2.data1)
from Table t1 join (select id, sum(amount) from Table group by id) t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
```

here, major problem is only how to get not null value among multiple columns. So we can achieve it by **coalesce function**.

**What coalesce function do?**

The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list.

**Example:**

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'W3Schools.com', NULL, 'Example.com');

After executing above sql query it returns.

```
W3Schools.com
```

which is first not null value.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

Answer (score 0):

select id, max(data1) data1,sum(amount) amount
from tablename
group by id

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, COALESCE(data1 ,'anyvalue') as data1, sum(amount) as amount 
from <table>
group by id , COALESCE(data1,'anyvalue')
```